# How to change the default facing font for a language in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: fonts, language-support, interface, arabic

I'm no fan of the Arabic interface font on Ubuntu, and I would like to change it. However, I don't readily see any option to do that.

How can I change the default font for a particular language (like Arabic) in Ubuntu 22.10?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer specific to Arabic, not to any particular language.

1. You can install the Arabic language support and switch to Arabic as your language to display messages and menus. That will give you a Noto Arabic font instead.
2. If you don't want Arabic as your display language, instead you can do:

   ```
   sudo apt install fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-ui-core
   sudo locale-gen ar_EG.UTF-8
   sudo update-locale LC_CTYPE=ar_EG.UTF-8
   ```

   and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Gunnar. However, this doesn't seem to work anymore starting in Ubuntu 22.10. What modifications must I make in order to get it to work?

Comment: @facialrecognition: Option 2. works for me in Ubuntu's development version (coming 23.04). I'm not aware of any change in 22.10 that would affect this.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to change arabic font only in chrome browser :

first you might need to install the (noto) font as replied above
then

Go to setting > search for fonts > Customize fonts
In the standard font choose **“noto naskh arabic ui”**

Hope it helps.